# Python - Creating a list of X's and Y's in every order they can occur

Tags: python, list, element

Where the length of each element is n.
For example if I would like to make a list of X's and Y's 1 time
then => ['X', 'Y']

2 times:
=> ['XX,'YY','XY','YX']

3 time:
=> ['XXX', 'YYY', 'XYY', 'XYX', 'XXY', 'YYX' etc...]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
for i in xrange(1, 4):
    print ["".join(item) for item in product("01", repeat = i)]

# ['0', '1']
# ['00', '01', '10', '11']
# ['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

Comment: Would there be another way to do this without using loops? Such as using recursion?

Comment: @user3422146 The loop here is just to demonstrate the usage of `product` for multiple values of `i`. You don't need to loop at all. Just try `["".join(item) for item in product("01", repeat = 2)]`

Comment: Oh thanks, but for that code is that an application of user itertools.product you mentioned?

Comment: @user3422146 yes, `product` function is in `itertools` module.

Comment: Would using the itertools be the only way for solving this problem?

Comment: @user3422146 That is the simplest way to solve this problem. Otherwise you have to use `n` loops :(

Comment: @user3422146 thefourtheye is right. This is exactly what I would have told you to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think combinations_with_replacement is what you're looking for. Here's an example for 0-5.

```
from itertools import *
for i in range(5):
    print(list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement("XY",i)))
```

Output:

```
 [()]
 [('X',), ('Y',)]
 [('X', 'X'), ('X', 'Y'), ('Y', 'Y')]
 [('X', 'X', 'X'), ('X', 'X', 'Y'), ('X', 'Y', 'Y'), ('Y', 'Y', 'Y')]
 [('X', 'X', 'X', 'X'), ('X', 'X', 'X', 'Y'), ('X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'), ('X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'), ('Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y')]
```

Comment: order matters, so this doesn't cover it.

Comment: Oh, I see. I just looked at him first example of X and Y => ['X', 'Y'] which didn't include ['Y','X'] so it wasn't clear.

Comment: maybe permutations with replacement? Does that exist?

Comment: That's what product is, so I think thefourtheye in the above comment has him covered.